# Maven Dependency for Android NDK?

Tags: android, maven-2

I am currently working on an Android project where I'd have to use maven.

Now, I am trying to study the Android NDK.

My question goes. Since NDK is a separate Suite(or however you call it), do I have to declare another dependency on my maven?

I would want to, but my question is whether or not there is a need. Or does the previous Android dependency cover it all?

Well considering the little understanding i have dug so far, it could hardly be possible for ndk to have a single jar library right?

So that I am not considering at all. But I'm a dumb child so...I thought it might be worth mentioning. :) I'm pretty new at everything.

From maven to Android to NDK and to the whole programming thing as a whole so please idiot-proof your answers for me...cheers! ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install your NDK and set up the environment variable ANDROID_NDK_HOME. Look at the [Android chapter of the book Maven The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev.html) that I just updated, as well as the NDK samples that come part of the [samples project](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples) for more info and examples.

If you still have more questions post on the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/maven-android-developers)..

Comment: oh my..thank you so much for the answer sir. Maven-Android is not exactly the most ubiquitous partnership right now and it has been hard to find good sources. I'm a huge fan. Simpligility. WoW. And Ksoap2-android. WOW. Marvelous. Thank you sir. So, is this to say that After declaring an environment variable for android ndk, I'm good to go? I actually already declared ANDROID_NDK_HOME before you told me(coincidence) for convenience in building the native codes. So now, aside from the previous default android dependency to maven, there would be no need to declare another specific for ndk? thanks

Comment: yes i did look at the samples..and from then on, it was crystal clear. thanks! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Since you choose to use Maven, you agree to let Maven manage your dependencies, which is convenient for the team to share the same version of particular dependency. So it's not a 'need' but a 'must-do'

Not sure about what're your 'previous Android dependency', but android-maven-plugin has a [mojo to support ndk build](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/ndk-build-mojo.html).

Btw, you can also host internal Maven repository for some jars that don't exist in public repository, using Artifactory for example.